# Implement annotation processor that allows to call method only if variable annotated with annotation (like Rust mut)

Tags: java, kotlin, annotation-processing

I think it's better to start with the idea I want to implement. I'm really inspired by Rust mut pointers so the same type can be immutable and mutable at same time. And I'm thinking is it possible to implement something like this for JVM.

It looks I just need to create annotation @Mutates to annotate methods that changes current class state and annotation @Mutable to annotate local variable, fields and args. Logic of processor is not too hard. For every invocation of method annotated by @Mutates I need to check that corresponding variable/field/arg is annotated by @Mutable. And if method calls any @Mutates method on fields or does assignment (= operator) that method must be annotated by @Mutates as well.

The main problem I don't know where to start as I don't have experience with annotation processing. From my limited understanding I can't use Annotation Processor as it isn't supposed analyze code of methods... So it seems I need to create some compiler plugin (two: for Java and for Kotlin).

Can somebody give me a piece of advice - is it possible at all to do that and how hard is this (so I can estimate efforts and time I will need for that and decide is it worthwhile or not)

Comment: Annotation processors are not supposed to change the actual class code, but to generate new source code, In your case what you can do is to generate a new class that maybe extend from the original class and override the methods to make the desired check and then delegate the call to the base method. taking a look at http://immutables.github.io might be a good idea as they do it with annotation processors

Answer (score 1):

The standard annotation processing interface does not provide access to the bodies of methods.  However, other frameworks do.  For example, the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) provides an API for annotation processing that descends into method bodies.  Building on the Checker Framework, you can [create an annotation processor](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#creating-a-checker) that enforces your mutability rules at compile time:  the annotation processor would halt compilation with a javac error message if a rule is violated.

Dozens of annotation processors have been built on the Checker Framework, and it is used daily at Amazon, Facebook, Google, Uber, etc.

Disclaimer:  I am one of the maintainers of the project.